# Crear varios eventos en MySQL desde PHP con diferentes nombres

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Quiero crear varios eventos en MySQL de forma dinámica desde PHP, pero no puedo hacerlo porque no puedo poner una variable PHP en el nombre del evento. Tengo la siguiente consulta, la cual no funciona porque tengo una variable después de CREATE EVENT.

```php
    CREATE EVENT '".$nombre."' ON SCHEDULE AT '".$fecha."' DO UPDATE `accounts` SET `position` = '".$newHex."'
```

Lo que pongo a continuación si funciona, pero entonces no puedo hacerlo de manera dinámica, creando muchos eventos como yo quiero.

```php
    CREATE EVENT nombre ON SCHEDULE AT '".$fecha."' DO UPDATE `accounts` SET `position` = '".$newHex."'
```

Lo que quiero llegar a conseguir es crear varios eventos que inserten en diferentes fechas, el tiempo no es constante entre unos y otros. Me gustaría conseguir crear algo así, quizás alguien conozca otra manera:
Esto serian las consultas creadas desde PHP

```
CREATE EVENT nombre1 ON SCHEDULE AT 2019-12-03 22:48:17 DO UPDATE `accounts` SET `posicion` = 0001

CREATE EVENT nombre2 ON SCHEDULE AT 2019-12-03 23:15:17 DO UPDATE `accounts` SET `posicion` = 0002

CREATE EVENT nombre3 ON SCHEDULE AT 2019-12-03 23:21:44 DO UPDATE `accounts` SET `posicion` = 0003
```

El único problema es que si pongo por ejemplo CREATE EVENT $nombre deja de funcionar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error se debe a que no podes usar comillas para el nombre del evento, por lo que la solución es simplemente omitirlas.

#### Ejemplo:

```
$event = "CREATE EVENT $nombre ON SCHEDULE AT '$fecha' DO UPDATE `accounts` SET `position` = '$newHex'";
```

Comment: No me puedo creer que finalmente fuera esa la solución... de echo lo probé antes pero había otra cosa mal y me daba error. Ya lo he solucionado ¡Gracias!